# Color does not affect Kivy Bubble background

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

The `Bubble` widget has a `background_color` property, which represents the RGBA color of the background. It also has a `background_image` property, which is self-explanatory. But changing the `background_color` does nothing to how the bubble looks, unlike a `Button`, for example, where changing it would apply a tint to the `background_image`. What makes the `Bubble`'s property behave differently?

Kivy v1.9.2-dev0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of tricky this one! This is the same as tinting, however it works **only** when you set it like this:

```
background_image = <something> # (1) or
background_image = ''          # (2)
# then it'll tint the image(1) or the bubble itself(2)
background_color = (1, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

It works also for `arrow_image`, but as in the first image, you need to set it first too:

```
arrow_image = ''
background_color = (1, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

However this one looks only as a `Rectangle` filled with a `Color`, so the best thing would be `.png` with transparent parts.

Comment: I kinda like the default texture so I copied it from the default and tried to apply it. While it is tinted, the tint is achieved by a plain rectangle of color behind the selected image, so the edges of this rectangle are visible behind the rounded texture. Is there a way to only apply the tint to the texture and not around it, or would it be better to simply draw a custom texture?

Comment: When you use `background_image=''` I think the original texture remains there (check the bubble.py to be sure). I see that you probably want the rounded corners or something similar, so basically the best solution would be either to use already tinted `.png` or to use canvas instructions same as for rounded corners and you'd tint the inner part.